# How To Use Trakt.TV API To Retrieve Movie List With Language Filter?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am trying to use the Trakt.tv API to retrieve a recently released movie list with a language filter. For example, I would only like to get a list of the latest 100 movies that have been recently released that have a primary language of French. I can't seem to figure out if this is even possible or am I stuck with retrieving the generic list?

Comment: What do their API docs say?

Comment: @jonrshape I cannot seem to find anything regarding pulling a recently released list using any sort of filters. Maybe I am not looking in the right area? This is where I am looking [link](https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/#reference/movies/popular/get-popular-movies)